# Походження вислову "всипати по перше число"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

[Словник фразеологізмів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53394/356843.html)

> ***вси́пати по пе́рше (по шо́сте) число́*** кому і без додатка. Суворо покарати, провчити кого-небудь. — Кинувся кожен: де Маковей? Де
> телефоніст? Розшукати негайно! Всипати по перше число! (О. Гончар); —
> Я вам покажу “точно”! — спалахнув Гречкун.— Чого не доповіли про
> готовність батальйону? Я вам всиплю по шосте число! Я вас навчу
> воювати (Ю. Бедзик).

Коли говорять "всиплю по перше число", то зрозуміло, що чекати на сильне покарання.

Яке походження вислову? Чомусаме перше (шосте) число?

Answer (score 2):

Я часто пишу, що точно встановити походження того чи іншого фразеологізму інколи неможливо. Однак, зазвичай є версії походження, так само як і з висловом "вси́пати по пе́рше (по шо́сте) число́". Згідно до сайтів [Моя Освіта](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/istoriya/chomu-kazhut-vsipati-po-pershe-chislo/) та [Тут Цікаво](http://tut-cikavo.com/krylati-frazy/640-vsipati-po-pershe-chislo-pokhodzhennya-virazu) (це не офіційні джерела, тому інформація не є на 100% достовірною):

> За старих часів в школі учнів часто шмагали, іноді навіть без
>   проступків з їх боку, просто для профілактики. Наставник міг проявити
>   старанність у виховних роботах і діставалося учням часом дуже сильно.
>   **Таких учнів могли звільнити від шмагань, аж до першого числа наступного місяця**.

Також я наткнувся на [міні-твір](http://www.rudenko.ho.com.ua/Mova/CaseStudy/15.pdf) з фразеологізмами, де пояснення цього вислову таке ж як і в попередніх джерелах.

Comment: У мене вкрай негативне ставлення до сайту «Моя освіта», бо я наразі не бачив на ньому жодної справжньої статті, лише неавторизовані переклади російських статей (у цьому разі не знаю звідси, можливо з [«Почему говорят „всыпать по первое число“?»](https://wexplain.ru/pochemu-govoryat-vsypat-po-pervoe-chislo/)). Хоча що краще — дати посилання на російський оригінал (із зазначенням, мовляв, тут про рос. мову, але, імовірно, походження подібне) чи дати посилання на український передрук (можливо, кепсько зроблений) — я навіть сам не знаю.